# Creating variables out of returned CSV data

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to create a simple cinema booking system using Python and a CSV file where 0 is a free seat and 1 is an empty seat. At the minute, the user enters the desired amount of seats and row required (A-J). The program should then check whether the row has room available in a single block.

At the minute it returns the values 0 and 1 along with the amount of free seats available on that row. I'm struggling however to determine whether there is a block of free seats available which is large enough for the amount of seats required. Any ideas?

Currently returns

```
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
A
Spaces available:  5
```

with the code

```
import csv

Section = 0
LargeBlock = 0
Spaces = 0
LastSpace = 0

SpacesReq = int(input("How many spaces do you require? (8 Max.) "))
while SpacesReq > 8:
    print("Invalid amount.")
    break
SectionReq = input("What row would you like to check between A- J? (Uppercase required) ")

with open('data.csv', 'rt') as file:
    open_f = csv.reader(file,  delimiter=',')

    for line in open_f:
        for item in line:
            if line[10] == SectionReq:
                print(item)
                if item == "0":
                    Spaces = Spaces + 1 
print("Spaces available: ", Spaces)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to empty blocks, so looping on line is a good idea: when you encounter a 0, increment the block size; if you encounter a 1, block size shall be reset to 0.

But you have something simpler, if you consider your lines as strings:

```
for line in open_f:
    if line[10]==SectionReq:
        SearchedBlock = '0'*SpacesReq
        strLine = ''.join(str(i) for i in line)
        if SearchBlock in strLine:
            # empty block found
            break
```